# error: supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath

Tags: android, compilation, kotlin

I can't compile my Android Kotlin project.

I have no idea what is this...

**Gradle log:**

error: supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
class android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity, unresolved supertypes: SupportParentable

**build.gradle (app)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.android_plugin_version = "2.3.3"
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-5'

    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$android_plugin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

def compat_version = '26.+'
def play_services_version = '11.0.1'
def firebase_version = '9.6.1'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.site.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["library" : "true"]
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
    correctErrorTypes = true
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // android
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${compat_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${compat_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${compat_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${compat_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${compat_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:${play_services_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:${play_services_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${play_services_version}"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"

    // kotlin
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Answer (score 67):

In my case I had a library module with an abstract application class implementing Dagger's `HasActivityInjector` and an application module with a dependency to the library and its own (non-abstract) application class extending the base app class.

My Gradle dependencies were `implementation`s, and therefore not accessible to the application module's application class (even though there were no imports there, otherwise the issue would be immediately obvious as you'd get a 'could not resolve' error. The fix was to replace dagger `implementation` dependencies with `api`, that makes them available to dependant modules as well.

Comment: I have forgotten to add the `Dagger` dependency to the module whose class I was using. `implementation` should be enough, if it is explicitly added to the module. (Thanks for the idea btw, you saved me from a couple hours debugging.)

Comment: do you mean if we use the library by "adding it as module", then we need to write dependencies defined in that library in "app" module? why?

Comment: In my case this error was happening when trying to access a method on a fragment. To avoid applying api configuration just for this error, I just created an interface and implement it on the fragment.

Comment: @oblakr24  What is you do not want to use `api` and you want to remain `implementation`? The issue lies with inheritance using an abstract class. Is there any work other workarounds for this without changing implementation to api?

Comment: i had a similar problem in dagger hilt, in the module with an abstract class I DID NOT have a dependency on dagger (only had the javax.inject:javax.inject:1 dependency), after I added the dagger dependencies in the module with an abstract class the problem got resolved

Answer (score 15):

I fixed it by changing the order of plugins call!

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.android_plugin_version = '2.3.3'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$android_plugin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // kotlin
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$android_plugin_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    // android
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${compat_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${compat_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${compat_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${compat_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${compat_version}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:${compat_version}"
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:${play_services_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${play_services_version}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${play_services_version}"
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'

    // fabric
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    // logger
    compile 'com.orhanobut:logger:2.1.1'

    // dexter
    compile 'com.karumi:dexter:4.1.0'

    // firebase
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${firebase_version}"

    // persistence
    compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha3"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha3"

    // facebook
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'

    // retrofit
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    // gson
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'

    // jobs
    compile 'com.evernote:android-job:1.1.11'

    // chart
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.1'

    // fresco
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.3.0'

    // indicator
    compile 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
}
```

Comment: Why would the order matter?  Does gradle.org specify that

Answer (score 15):

Before trying anything else, try:
    Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate cache/restart

This worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was child module not using AndroidX Activity. I guess the class names clashed.

Added this to resolve:

`implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'`

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem by deleting files related with `dagger hilt` from `java(generated)` and `rebuild` my project

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to add same dependencies in the project level as well which are added to the module

Answer (score 1):

(App)-----depends----(library)

In my case I did not change any dependencies configuration nor i change the order.
I had to copy a local pojo(model) jar file from the library module to App.

App is in kotlin
library is in java

Its a bug, I should not have pojo.jar in app and library

Comment: This solution worked. Thanks. Can we do it without moving library dependencies to app module? Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Clean Project and Rebuild it This works for me

Comment: This does not answer the question and should be removed. If you want to comment on a post, you should provide [actual answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to earn the reputation necessary to comment (which is 50, see [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges))

Comment: @finnmglas why do you view this as not being an answer? W

Comment: @broc.seib It appeared to be more of a comment than an answer (especially as Sangeetha's reputation was below 50). The question was solved by other answers showing the problem was way more complex than something that goes away by rebuilding :D

Comment: @finnmglas Thanks that you are very much concerned about the answer and Even I had the same problem and it is solved by just rebuilding my project and I thought it might help him and I hope I didn't add something which is not necessary on this forum

Comment: @broc.seib Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well in my case this error randomly occurs which usually occurs during execution through Android Studio.

The root cause was that My Activity class were extending some interfaces which was in another nested package:

**package tv.activities**

```
public class MainActivity implements MyListener {

}
```

**package tv.activities.error**

```
interface MyListener {

}
```

Hence it usually happens during execution but after second run it resolves automatically so no one bother to resolve it. Sometimes Android Studio fail to recognise that interface is accessible so there is no sense of showing error for the same:

```
Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class tv.activities.MainActivity, unresolved supertypes: MyListener
```

**Final Solution:**

**Making interface public resolves this issue permanently.**

```
public interface MyListener {
}
```

Or refactor the package accessibility where AS doesn't get confuse

Comment: Aren't interfaces public in Java?

Answer (score 0):

On my case I had to add the required dependency on my main module and compile the last version with:

```
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:${picassoVersion}"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error for below lib in app level build.gradle

```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.2'
```

So the solution is the order in project level build.gradle, So
**before solving error the structure was**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {

    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {

    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    }

}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**After Solving the error the struture is :**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
     maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()


}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    }
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()


}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**By default it tries to download using google() as it comes first in the sequence but when we move maven on top of all then it creates the build again using maven and the build succeeds**. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

When setting up the crashlytics to my app, I used "recommended" dependency as well, as shown below. But this was the part causes error.

```
// Firebase Crashlytics
// (Recommended) Add the Google Analytics dependency.
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
```

Removing "analytics" line solved my problem.

```
// Firebase Crashlytics
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
```

Hope this helps someone else too,

best

Comment: This Didn't help in my case!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error upgrading others libraries.
My error showed when I added firebase=ads (from google adsmob). 
So I found a conflict in my firebase-auth (16.0.5) and firebase ads (19.0.1).

Migrating firebase to 19.3.0 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had removed an unused `OnFragmentInteractionListener` in a fragment:

```
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

However, In my activity I had failed to remove a reference to this `OnFragmentInteractionListener` :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        MyFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {
```

Strangely, instead of giving an error that indicated the `OnFragmentInteractionListener` was not found, I received the above **"supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved"** with no reference to the classes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I went to the project structure and updated all firebase dependencies to the latest and the highest. At the moment here are implementations with their versions:

```
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my build folder and restarted the project
app/build

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32016303)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a same error after adding gradle dependency for api module. I was using `implementation(projects.someDependency)` which made things inaccessible in api module. Chaning that to `api(projects.someDependency)` worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Update your google play gradle version to the latest