# Showing error "Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved." without any class list

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, compiler-errors

Error:Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:

**Without any class list it's giving error**

[image]

I'm developing library. In that I created one class and used it in demo app importing. When I instantiate object of that class then it compiles successfully. But when I try to access getter methods at next line then it gives above error.

I'm not understanding where it's going wrong, because it does not showing any class name or error location.

**Can any one help??**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598848/error-supertypes-of-the-following-classes-cannot-be-resolved-please-make-sure

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778651/supertypes-of-the-following-classes-cannot-be-resolved-please-make-sure-you-hav

Comment: AndroidStudio is a bit naughty sometimes and doesn't give the full error. Try copy and pasting what you have into a text editor - it should have the full info there.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. 2nd answer solved my problem by upgrading kotlin.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778651/supertypes-of-the-following-classes-cannot-be-resolved-please-make-sure-you-hav)

Answer (score 3):

@Pamela Hill had the right answer, if you hover over the error on the left you'll see that there's more, and you can copy this into a text editor to see it the full output.

[image: screenshot]